# Unable to use calc to size image in carousel

Tags: angularjs, css, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm hoping this is a simple answer that I'm just overlooking. I've been toying around with the ui-bootstrap carousel directive, and wanted to size it dynamically to fill the space between my header and my footer.

My header and footer are each divs that are 70px in height. The carousel works just fine when I let it do it's own thing, and just plug the images in. However the images are rather large and not all the same size. I thought maybe it was an issue with the `img` tag so I changed it to a `div` and just set the images as the background of each one with the height set to `calc(100% - 70px - 70px)`. However the div's never seem to actually get the calculated height (they always have a height of 0).

after searching online, I have set the `html` and `body` tags to `height: 100%` already, so that isn't the issue.

Given it's kind of hard to explain, please reference
[this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/k86L6aOHGt7INrl5KuiK?p=preview)

Comment: Try just `calc(100% - 140px)`.  Also, 100% of what?

Comment: I don’t see any result in that plunkr …

Comment: @CBroe That's kind of the point. You can see the left arrow of the carousel at the top left after a few seconds, but that's it. If you inspect element on it in Chrome, and manually assign the div with a class of 'slide-image' a height of 300px or something, it will appear.

Comment: Well, as @sideroxylon already asked, 100% of _what_? The parent of that element does not have an explicit height set, so you simply can’t expect percentages to work for the children. But you could of course use `calc(100vh - 140px)`, if your OK with limited support in older browsers.

Comment: @CBroe okay, that makes total sense. I had a suspicion that may have been the case, but I couldn't seem to get the elements created by the angular directives to have a size either. If you would go ahead and put your `100vh` comments as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heights given percentages only work if the parent element has an explicit height set as well – you don’t have that here, so it can’t work, whether used in `calc()` or as `height: x%` directly.

But you could of course use `calc(100vh - 140px)`, if you are OK with [limited support in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)¹. `100vh` is 100% of the viewport height, but it doesn’t need to have a height set on all parent elements up to the `html` element (as `height:100%` would require to achieve the same thing).

---

¹ Be aware that the Known Issues at caniuse mention that *“Safari & iOS Safari (both 6 and 7) does not support viewport units […] in calc().”* Depending on whether you need those, that might be a deal breaker. In that case, you might try and go with absolute (or fixed) positioning (70px from `top` and `bottom` each) for the carousel container. That way, it would have a defined height again, and 100% for the child elements should work.